# How to blink light for my iphone app

Tags: iphone, animation

i am developing a game.when app starts,video will start to play like this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OeuwYIYC0w

After opening gate button will press and timer will start and light will be blinking after 4,5 sec it blinks fast and after that all screen will become red.

**So how to blink light on this video any one can help me......**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS5 you can access main screen brightness:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
//
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Fading In Fading out  animation you can do that where alpha=0.0 /alpha=1.0

animation code

```
myimageView.alpha=0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[myImageView setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```